# Web.config redirect outside traffic for testing purposes

Tags: asp.net, web-config, redirect

This is a bit of a tricky question.

I am developing a .net website, and it is hosted on our own servers.
I want to redirect outside traffic to a blank "coming soon" page, while our internal network can see the content.

How do I modify the web.config to do that?

I have already tried default document settings, but it doesn't seem to accept those, and instead displays the .NET website.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module. It shows how to use IIS URL Rewrite Module (which in turns writes to web.config) to handle your scenario.